# Controlling the randomness of DropoutLayer

Tags: random, neural-networks

How can I control the randomness of `DropoutLayer` in order to get the same result after each execution?

For example:

```
drop = DropoutLayer[];
drop[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, NetEvaluationMode -> "Train"]
```

As it is written under Possible Issues (in the Documentation Center) for `DropoutLayer`:

> Currently, any randomness invoked by NetEvaluationMode->"Train" is not affected by SeedRandom and BlockRandom

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
net = NetGraph[
  {
   ThreadingLayer[Times]
   },
  {
   {NetPort["Input"], NetPort["Dropout"]} -> 1
   }
  ]
```

[image]

```
dropout[size_, p_Real: 0.5] := RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {0, 1}, size]

Table[net[<|"Input" -> Range[6], "Dropout" -> dropout[{6}]|>], {10}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Table[SeedRandom[0]; net[<|"Input" -> Range[6], "Dropout" -> dropout[{6}]|>], {10}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**EXAMPLE**

```
net = NetGraph[
  <|
   "dropout" -> NetGraph[{ThreadingLayer[Times]}, {{NetPort["Input"], NetPort["Dropout"]} -> 1}],
   "classify" -> {2, SoftmaxLayer[]}
   |>,
  {"dropout" -> "classify"},
  "Input" -> 3,
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]
  ]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[0];
n = 10;
data = Thread[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}] -> RandomInteger[{0, 1}, n]];

generator = Function[
   With[
    {x = RandomSample[data, #BatchSize]},
    <|
     "Input" -> x[[;; , 1]],
     "Output" -> x[[;; , 2]],
     "Dropout" -> dropout[{#BatchSize, 3(*same size as Input*)}]
     |>
    ]
   ];

SeedRandom[0];
netT = NetTrain[net, generator, MaxTrainingRounds -> 1, BatchSize -> 2]
```

[image]

For evaluation we need to replace custom dropout layer with `DropoutLayer` which has the same probability.

```
netT = RightComposition[
   NetExtract[#, "classify"] &,
   NetPrepend[#, DropoutLayer[0.5]] &,
   NetReplacePart[#, "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]] &
   ]@netT
```

[image]

```
netT[{1, 2, 3}, "Probabilities"]
```

> <|0 -> 0.0449557, 1 -> 0.955044|>

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexey! You define your own dropout layer in order to get the control of randomness, which is fine. But my question was specifically for the built-in Mathematica command DropoutLayer. Is it possible to fix the SeedRandom as it is done in TensorFlow and PyTorch (for example)?

Comment: @demm No, it's impossible. Will likely be fixed in Mathematica 12.

Comment: Interestingly, within LSTMs, GNNs etc. the internal dropout option (Dropout, for the gate contributions) is fixed by setting a SeedRandom before NetInitialize.

Answer (score 5):

If you find that there is no equivalent operation in `NeuralNetwoks` like `TensorFlow` or `PyTorch`, you should ask `` <<MXNetLink` `` for help.

```
drop=DropoutLayer[];
do:=(
    MXNetLink`MXSeedRandom[42];
    drop[Range@5,NetEvaluationMode->"Train"]
);
SameQ@Table[do,100]
```

`do` should return array `0` forever.

---

**PS:**

`NeuralNetwoks` is something like `Keras || FastAI`.

`MXNet` is at the same level as `TensorFlow & PyTorch`.

Comment: `TargetDevice -> "CPU"`: `{0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}`
`TargetDevice -> "GPU"`: `{2., 4., 6., 0., 0.}`

Comment: https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/pull/12091 "...on the CPU and GPU the random number generator works slightly differently. On the CPU the numbers are generated in the range [0,1) and on the GPU they are (0,1]."